# Update autoscaling group AMIs and running instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm trying to setup the following for a project

- EC2 instances in an auto scaling group, behind an elastic load balancer
- A CodeDeploy application to deploy new versions of my application to the EC2 instances

I have a question regarding the AMIs on which the EC2 instances are based. If I want to make some changes to the systems' configuration (say update the **libssl** package), I see two options:

- (1) run packer / manually create a new AMI and setup my auto scaling group to use it. Then, restart the instances so they use the new AMI. This is obviously really slow and causes downtime.
- (2) use a configuration management tool such as Ansible to run **yum update libssl** on the instances, but this would not persist the changes to the instances launched in the future
- (3) create a new AMI (manually or using packer) **and** then use a configuration management tool to shut down the old instances and run new ones using the new AMI. This is the option I think is the best, but I'm not sure how to do it in detail, neither how to avoid downtime. Also, it would remain quite slow (~10min I guess)

What would be the best way to do this (avoiding downtime)? Are there some best practise I should stick to?

Thanks

***[Edit]*** I came accross [aws-ha-release](https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/tree/master/aws-ha-release) from aws-missing-tools, which enables to restart all instances from an auto scaling group without any downtime. I guess this could be used in conjunction with packer to force the running instance to use the new AMI. Any feedback on this? I feel like it's a little bit hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options:

## 1 Use Two Autoscale Groups

If you are trying to prevent downtime while deploying new code, take advantage of the fact that **an ELB can have multiple autoscale groups/launch configs** associated to it.

You can have:

- **autoscale-A, launchconfig-A** which are the autoscale group and launch
  configs of your version "A" of your servers.
- **autoscale-B, launchconfig-B** which are the autoscale group and launch configs of
  your verison "B" of your servers.

**A** represents **version X** of the code, and **B** represents **version X+1** (including any changes to O/S configuration such as **libssl**)

Now when you want to roll out version X + 1 of your code, simple "bake" a new AMI, configured exactly how you like it, and add the autoscale group B to the elb. Once the autoscale group and its instances are in service, set the max/capacity of the autoscale group A to 0, taking the version X servers out of the ELB. Only your version X + 1 will be running. When new instances come up in the future e.g. if a server fails, they'll be using your X + 1 AMI and have all of it's configuration changes.

Note if your application talks to a database, you will need to ensure that version X of the code and version X + 1 can operate on the same version of the database e.g. if version X + 1 removes a table that version X uses, then you'll get errors from users hitting verison X of your application. #1 works well when there are either no database changes in your code release, or if you've built in backwards compatibility when you roll out a new version of the code.

## 2 Combine Config Management Tool with the Health Check

If all you are wanting to do is update the O/S e.g. patch a version, then you can combine your thought of using a tool like Ansible with the ELB health check.

- When you want to patch a server, scale up your number of instances
  temporarily e.g. if you were running 3 instances, scale up to 6.
- As part of their user data, run Ansible and only once it
  succesfully completes e.g. to update libssl, do you allow the health
  check to pass and the EC2 instance to serve traffic from the ELB.
- Once the ELB is successfully seeing the new EC2 instances, scale down
  the number of instances in the auto scale group to its original capacity (in this case, 3).
- **Note: The oldest
  instances will be the ones that AWS terminates**, meaning that the only instances that will be left running are your 3 new instances.
- If an instance fails and a new one spins up, it will start with your base AMI, apply any Ansible changes (and only once the changes are present, will the health check pass and it be put in service).
- (This is your (2) but fixes the issue of new instances not containing the libssl version change)

**Note on speed**

- **Option 1** will allow failed instances to be in service faster  than Option 2 (since you are not waiting on Ansible to run) at the expense of having to "pre-bake" your AMI.
- **Option 2** will allow you greater flexibility and speed for patching production servers e.g. if you need to "patch something *now*" this might be the quickest way. Having something like Ansible running and the ability to patch the O/S (separating that task from the deploying code task) can come with additional advantages, depending on your use case. Providing an agent-less hook into your server's configuration (libraries, user management, etc) is quite powerful, especially in the cloud.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Really helps.
What do you think of this solution: 
- define the configuration of the servers via an Ansible playbook
- configure the launch configuration to pull this playbook from a Git repository and execute it
This way, if I wanted to do something on the running machines, all I have to do is to update this playbook (so that future instances take the change into account) and to run it on the running machines.

I'm just wondering: how to run an ansible command on how instances in an autoscaling group? Couldn't find the info... Thanks again!

Comment: Nevermind: I think this should do the trick. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script
Would still love to hear your opinion about this solution, though. ;)

Comment: Yes, that is how I've done it. Note you could also have the playbook in s3 as a way of promoting your changes ("these are ready for production"). But pulling directly from git can work as well. Your second question has a typo in it so I'm not positive this will address it, however, check out the relatively new feature: EC2 Run Command: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-run-command-update-now-available-for-linux-instances/. Note I'd suggest instead of pushing out commands, you have a Cron on your machines that periodically runs Ansible and pulls in/executes updates. It scales better.

Comment: Woops, my question was "how to run an ansible command on *all* instances in an autoscaling group". The only issue I see with Ansible is that you run commands directly on the production systems. 
Thank you for your great answers.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you evaluate to use the userdata field of your Launch Configuration?

All in all it is 16 KB of pure love, built in in your recipe for spawning new machines.

If using Linux, then you use Bash script, if WIndows then you can use Powershell.

No additional tools, all integrated and for free.

P.S. If you need more than 16 KB, just chain a wget of your additional scripts in your core script and then shell it by creating a chain.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, user data enable to run bash scripts when an instance is created by the autoscaling group, right? That's not what I need (maybe my question isn't clear enough?)